# Java2D - Access font CMap to render ligatures

Tags: java, fonts, awt, java-2d

I need to print Emojis with ligatures ( +  =  ) into a Graphics2D object. From what I see you can either use `graphics2d.drawString(string, x, y);` or create a GlyphVector from the font and then print that GlyphVector into the Graphics2D object.

Both methods don't work as they fail rendering ligatures. There is an interesting method in Font: `createGlyphVector(frc, int[] glyphCodes)` that allow you to create a GlyphVector with the specified glyph indexes.

THE PROBLEM:

How do I retrieve such glyph indexes. Manually accessing the indexes for the ligature glyphs I could workaround the problem.

The `java.awt.Font` class hides all the API that allow you to access the CMap and I don't see any way in the standard API to access/query the glyphs.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: why not 
~~~~~
public GlyphVector createGlyphVector(FontRenderContext frc,
                                     char[] chars)
~~~~~

Comment: Because instead of emoji it renders a square. I think that basically there is a wrong Surrogate Pairs handling. And reading around also the font ligatures are not well supported.

Comment: ah. ligatures are notoriously difficult to get rendered by java2d. To the best of my knowledge there is no api to query a font for ligatures. Luckily,  many emojis have a single unicode character and should map to those glyphs directly (http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-released.html).

Comment: The support for Surrogate Pairs is not an option. Not only to render Emojis  but other script as well. So far the only solution look like being to use `sun.font.Font2D`

Comment: You should probably show (reduced to only a working minimum) code. Does combining http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UnicodeFontsandTextRendering.htm with a simple loop that generates the surrogate pairs using codepoint integer sequences not work?

Comment: No it won't. I already have the data split as surrogate pairs. I will update the question tomorrow with some code.

Comment: Ok I was able to print non-BMP codepoints such as Emoji. It was a problem of font. Now I still have the Ligatures problem. Does anybody now a workaround for it?

Answer (score 0):

I searched JAVA and found createGlyphVector(frc, int[]) which is all I need in order to use JAVA to display text from native code.

In my search I found this wonderful question that is exactly what I was looking for, to validate that we do have in JAVA DrawGlyphRuns D2D equivalent.

The alternative to using JAVA from native code is including a library such as freetype-gl and doing everything on native side.

So my solution to not having cmap data easily available in JAVA, is having it prepared in advance for specific fonts and made into resource data tables. This works very well and very quickly for scripts with reasonable amount of Unicode code points. The assumption is that cmap data is stable data. The tables take very little memory and it is good to not have to call functions for it for every glyph even when cmap data is readily available.